# Interfacing ESP32-C3-MINI-1 using Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I am doing a project wherein I need to store device states. Essentially I have a momentary button (that will act as a toggle) to control which LED will illuminate. However, I also need to send the state of the device to an app. I was thinking that the best way to do this is using a counter variable and the preferences.h library. The counter will count how many times the button has been pressed and depending on that number (will either be a 1 or 2), it will tell either LED1 or LED2 to turn on. Then with the preferences library, I would store the counter and communicate the number with the app (both states need to be communicated).

I am having trouble with the code for this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I have gotten the button to act as a toggle, but I don't know how to implement the counter with the preferences library with this. I also do have a base code that I am able to send pictures of if needed.

Comment: Hi Abhi, welcome to SO. Please post your code together with the question whenever possible. Please _do not_ post it as pictures, but copy and paste into your question as text, surrounded by the code tags: \`\`\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, here is a simple explanation of how to use the preferences.h on an ESP32

```
//include the library first
#include <Preferences.h>
Preferences myPrefs;

//in the setup
void setup(){
    .....
    
    //start the preferences within a "status" namespace, if the namespace doesn't exists it will be created
   // it doesn't have to be called "status", can be anything "myApp", "log","settings"....
   // once the namespace is created you can add keys with values to it

    myPrefs.begin("status", false);

}
```

anywhere else you can read the keys and change them, you can use a ton of different types of values, here I have only used an integer type so the commands are:

```
int something =  myPrefs.getInt("keyname",0) //read integer value and if it doesn't exists set the value to 0 (zero)

myPrefs.putInt("keyname", 1) //save this key to have value 1 it can be 2, 1000, 476529 etc...
```

nad Herę is a simple code that "remembers" the button clicks , on the first click it will light up led 1, on the second it will turn off led 1 and light up led 2 and on the third click it will turn both legs off. It can be written more efficiently of course but should give you an idea.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <Preferences.h>
Preferences myPrefs;

//change the pins to whatever you use
const int button_pin = 5;
const int led_1_pin = 6;
const int led_2_pin = 7;

int led_state = 0;

void setup(){

    Serial.begin(115200);

    myPrefs.begin("status", false); //start the preferences and if don't exists create one

    pinMode(button_pin,INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(led_1_pin,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led_2_pin,OUTPUT);

     led_state = myPrefs.getInt("led_state", 0); //read the saved state if there is one or set it to zero

    //set the led to the saved status
    if(led_state == 0){
        digitalWrite(led_1_pin,LOW);
        digitalWrite(led_2_pin,LOW);
    }else if(led_state == 1){
        digitalWrite(led_1_pin,HIGH);
    }else if(led_state == 2){
        digitalWrite(led_1_pin,HIGH);
    }

}


void loop(){


    if(digitalRead(button_pin) == LOW){ //button is pressed
        led_state++;

        //when the button is pressed after the Led 2 was on both leds will go off
        //change that to whatever logic you want
        if(led_state == 3){
            led_state = 0;
        }

        
        if(led_state == 0){
            digitalWrite(led_1_pin,LOW);
            digitalWrite(led_2_pin,LOW);
           
        }else if(led_state == 1){
            digitalWrite(led_1_pin,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(led_2_pin,LOW);
           
            
        }else if(led_state == 2){
            digitalWrite(led_1_pin,LOW);
            digitalWrite(led_2_pin,HIGH);
           
        }

        myPrefs.putInt("led_state", led_state); //save the current state to preferences

    }


}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Preferences in ESP32 Arduino does not use LittleFS. It's [implemented](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/preferences.html#about) on top of [NVS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/nvs_flash.html) which is a light-weight and reliable key-value database. It is almost always the best tool for storing key-value pairs.

Comment: Damn it's ESP32 not 8266...brain sees what brain wants to see! answer edited :-)

Comment: Awsome edit, an upvote from me :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This will be a great starting point for me :)